# GCM push notifications with Xamarin.Android and Parse Server - Manifest Error

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging

Currently I'm developing an App that connects with open source Parse Server hosted on Heroku . I've configured Parse Server with GCM to use Push Notifications . The Parse Cloud function which sends a push notification is this

```
    Parse.Cloud.define('pingReply', function(request, response) {
  var params = request.params;
  var customData = params.customData;

  if (!customData) {
    response.error("Missing customData!")
  }

  var sender = JSON.parse(customData).sender;
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo("installationId", sender);

  Parse.Push.send({
  where: query,
  // Parse.Push requires a dictionary, not a string.
  data: {"alert": "The Giants scored!"},
  }, { success: function() {
     console.log("#### PUSH OK");
  }, error: function(error) {
     console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
  }, useMasterKey: true});

  response.success('success');
});
```

So far so good . I get the response as success from Heroku Logs :

```
    Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse heroku/router: at=info method=POST path="/parse/functions/pingReply" host=fuseparse.herokuapp.com request_id=8fd137d9-5773-43be-b3f2-d63102681fbb fwd="91.187.123.178" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=12ms status=200 bytes=502 protocol=https 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse heroku/router: at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/_Installation" host=fuseparse.herokuapp.com request_id=366713f1-82a4-4cdf-bd4e-2edd90bb6aa0 fwd="91.187.123.178" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=200 bytes=542 protocol=https 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/functions/pingReply: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "customData": "{\n  \"sender\": \"02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32\"\n}" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } method=POST, url=/parse/functions/pingReply, host=fuseparse.herokuapp.com, connection=close, x-parse-application-id=fuseAppId10049932018, x-parse-client-version=net-xamarin-android1.7.0.0, x-parse-installation-id=02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32, x-parse-app-build-version=1, x-parse-app-display-version=1.0, x-parse-os-version=7.0, x-parse-windows-key=, x-parse-session-token=r:a418315ac756d4b7b52ff3b91c855443, content-type=application/json, if-modified-since=Sat, 14 Apr 2018 08:40:59 GMT, x-request-id=8fd137d9-5773-43be-b3f2-d63102681fbb, x-forwarded-for=91.187.123.178, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=0, x-request-start=1523695259737, total-route-time=0, content-length=77, customData={ 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "sender": "02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: info: Ran cloud function pingReply for user nZVF4du12E with: 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   Input: {"customData":"{\n  \"sender\": \"02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32\"\n}"} 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   Result: "success" functionName=pingReply, customData={ 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "sender": "02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: }, user=nZVF4du12E 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/functions/pingReply: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "response": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "result": "success" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } result=success 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/push: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "where": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "installationId": "02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   }, 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "data": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "alert": "The Giants scored!" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } method=POST, url=/parse/push, host=fuseparse.herokuapp.com, connection=close, user-agent=node-XMLHttpRequest, Parse/js1.11.1 (NodeJS 9.11.1), accept=*/*, content-type=text/plain, x-request-id=50529385-5a78-4ee7-a564-e7a65a399f82, x-forwarded-for=54.196.149.254, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=0, x-request-start=1523695259761, total-route-time=0, content-length=270, installationId=02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32, alert=The Giants scored! 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/push: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "headers": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "X-Parse-Push-Status-Id": "ZUxpLqNi8Q" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   }, 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "response": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "result": true 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } X-Parse-Push-Status-Id=ZUxpLqNi8Q, result=true 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: #### PUSH OK 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: REQUEST for [POST] /parse/classes/_Installation: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "channels": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "__op": "AddUnique", 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "objects": [ 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:       "abcd" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     ] 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } method=POST, url=/parse/classes/_Installation, host=fuseparse.herokuapp.com, connection=close, x-parse-application-id=fuseAppId10049932018, x-parse-client-version=net-xamarin-android1.7.0.0, x-parse-installation-id=02859607-7e76-44cb-b78c-a723064f9f32, x-parse-app-build-version=1, x-parse-app-display-version=1.0, x-parse-os-version=7.0, x-parse-windows-key=, x-parse-session-token=r:a418315ac756d4b7b52ff3b91c855443, content-type=application/json, if-modified-since=Sat, 14 Apr 2018 08:40:59 GMT, x-request-id=366713f1-82a4-4cdf-bd4e-2edd90bb6aa0, x-forwarded-for=91.187.123.178, x-forwarded-proto=https, x-forwarded-port=443, via=1.1 vegur, connect-time=0, x-request-start=1523695259779, total-route-time=0, content-length=52, __op=AddUnique, objects=[abcd] 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: verbose: RESPONSE from [POST] /parse/classes/_Installation: { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   "response": { 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "channels": [ 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:       "abcd" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     ], 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:     "updatedAt": "2018-04-14T08:40:59.792Z" 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1:   } 
Apr 14 01:41:00 fuseparse app/web.1: } channels=[abcd], updatedAt=2018-04-14T08:40:59.792Z
```

But the problem is that the notification isn't getting received by the Xamarin.Android . I think the source of error is this build error log :

```
    04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): Cannot use GCM for push because AndroidManifest.xml is missing:
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
04-14 15:43:42.098 W/parse.ManifestInfo(12218): <uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

This shouldnt be a problem because I've defined these permissions in the manifest like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.appname" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.companyname.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application android:label="Fuse.Android" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
                         android:value="@string/gcm_sender_id"/>

      <service android:name="parse.ParsePushService" />.

      <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.companyname.appname" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.parsePushBroadcastReceiver"
                android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

I've followed all the instructions given [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Push-Notifications-Setup-for-Parse)  and for the broadcast receiver I converted the receivers from [this Android Project](https://github.com/codepath/ParsePushNotificationExample) in C# . OnReceived never gets called obviously . The problem is the AndroidManifest but I don't get it what I'm doing wrong . I've searched all over for a Xamarin.Android implementation of Parse Server push but they are too old and use the hosted Parse.com .

Comment: Use FCM, not GCM, because Google is canceling GCM April 2019.

Comment: I switched to FCM . I integrated FCM to Parse Server and the client to use it . The problem is now if I build the Android app somewhere in the output log It says something like : Your sender id needs to have the id prefix (which i have it in my manifest like id:xxxxx) . when i execute the parse cloud  function it gives me a mismatchsenderid . Dont know where is the error , either FCM doesnt recgonize the senderid im sending from the app client or the parse server side is not configures properly for fcm .. any ideas ??

Comment: Hi Drinv! Open a new question on StackOverflow and attach the code + error logs

Comment: I opened a new question for this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843542/fcm-with-parse-server-push-notifications-mismatchsenderid-and-client-app-error